# How to remove extra comma in cur.fetchall()

Tags: python, sql

I tried to output all values in a column in mysql however, it also outputs extra comma in the end.

```
def numbers():
    db = getDB();
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT mobile_number FROM names"
    cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()

    for x in result:
        print(x)
```

It looks like this in shell:

```
(0123456789,)
(9876543210,)
```

Comment: The result is in a tuple, a Python data type. The comma doesn't technically exist. What are you intending to use this data for and how?

Comment: I think, the comma is there, to indicate that you got a tuple. So, don't `print(x)`, but `print(x[0])`

Comment: Does that in python by default stores in tuple as tupple is immutable

Comment: thank you @Dschoni it solves the problem! Thank you appreciate it sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple more options:

```
# validate that the results contain exactly one column
for [x] in result:
    print(x)
```

and

```
# using argument unpacking
for x in result:
    print(*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically as Ben's comment says the comma doesn't technically exist, it is there because it is a tuple.

but is you still want to remove it try this:

```
rows=[i[0] for i in rows]
```